# Prevent Unity optimizing local variables out

Tags: unity, debugging

Is there a way to instruct Unity compiler **not** optimize (best only for builds run from Unity editor)? More precisely, I would like it to stop removing local variables, because it complicates debugging. For example, inspecting `node`

```
void Generate() {
   var node = new Node();
   node = node; //breakpoint here, node cannot be inspected
   var x_nearest = Nearest(new_node);
   Debug.Log(new_node);//new_node still cannot be inspected, but x_nearest can
}
Node Nearest(Node node)
{
   //node is an argument here and can be inspected
}
```

in Visual Studio produces error rather than displaying its value.

> The identifier `node` is not in the scope

A solution would be make every local variable a private member instead:

```
private Node node;
void Generate() {
   node = new Node();
   node = node; //breakpoint here, node can be inspected
}
```

this would, however require frequent back and forth refactoring. I am using Unity 5.6.0f3 with [C# 6.0 support](https://bitbucket.org/alexzzzz/unity-c-5.0-and-6.0-integration/src) and Visual Studio 2017.
*note: provided code is for illustration only and the question is not about debugging said code because reproducing specific compiler behavior is not trivial*

Comment: I can't say for sure, but it sounds like it might be an issue with Visual Studio debugger with Unity. I frequently use the debugger in Monodevelop and I can inspect local variables at breakpoints without a problem.

Comment: I think its the fact that `node = node` is a useless line (it does nothing) so it gets removed.  Then `var node = new Node()` does nothing because the object is never used, so *that* gets compiled out.  Do `Debug.Log(node)` instead of `node = node` and try that.

Comment: @Draco18s `Debug.Log` had not effect - the `node` is not unused, there is more logic in the function - if I step inside a function `var x_nearest = Nearest(new_node);` the `new_node` is within said function argument and is inspectable. This *might* be bug in VS as @Tartle Wizard said, but if it is inspectable when passed as argument it really looks like non-existent variable in time of execution. Maybe I should change the title, but I am not sure what would better describe the problem?

Comment: Try setting the variable as volatile. That should force the compiler to disable any optimization related to that variable. So, a line like this: `volatile Node node = new Node();` should do what you need it to do. (Also, try not to use var to declare variables. It's just good practice to actually call it what it is.)

Comment: @JohnHamilton Local variables cannot be declared volatile. For the`var` keyword the "official" rule is that everything except primitive types should be declared var, unless it impairs the readability.

Comment: @wondra Ew. Who wrote that rule? Why would you ever want inferred types?